# iOS birthday calendar duplicates not removable

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, calendar

My iPhone is suffering from a bug which seems to be quite common and talked about on the web. Despite my research on Google, [Apple Forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7671336) and [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/161447/ridiculous-number-of-unnecessary-empty-birthday-calendars-that-cant-be-deleted) I still not have a solution...

In the iOS Calendar App there is 2 'Birthday' calendars bellow the 'other' section when I tap the 'Calendars' button at the bottom of the screen and there is no option to remove them (neither in the app nor in the iPhone Settings). The only available option is to uncheck them.

Strangely only one contains birthdays from my Contacts Adresse Book while the other one is empty.

I only use iCloud for Contacts, Calendar and Reminders accounts (my other Google and Exchange accounts are set on Mail only).

I tried many solutions found around the web including ones given by Apple (turning off Calendar, Contacts and Reminders in iCloud settings, and then turning back on after a while), I tried solutions given by users (closing apps, deactivate iCloud, rebooting the phone) and I tried restoring my iPhone.

**Note:** I have an iPhone 7 Plus with iOS 11 installed and an early-2015 MacBookAir. I'm also using iCloud since the beginning of its existence.

Thank you in advance for your help!

---

**EDIT:**

As asked in the comments here is somes screenshots for clarity (feel free to ask more, i'll upload as soon as possible).

Sorry for the French language in second screenshot (as well as for the cropped aspect, I don't have access to a computer for now). Note that I tried to uncheck the "show birthday calendar" in iCloud Calendar Settings and  when I came back later it was still enabled (I didn't forget to hit the save button, however and I tried several times).

[image: Calendar App]
[image: iCloud.com Calendar App]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ridiculous number of unnecessary empty birthday calendars that can't be deleted](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/161447/ridiculous-number-of-unnecessary-empty-birthday-calendars-that-cant-be-deleted)

Comment: As stated in my question I already tried the solutions developed in this exact topic on Ask Different. You may have noticed that this question is quite outdated and the accepted answer points out a software update (that should ave been resolved with the device restauration I performed 2 days ago).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that worked was to restore the iPhone and to configure it as "new iPhone". That is to say without using an iCloud or iTunes backup.

I enabled back iCloud (with my contacts, calendars...) and downloaded manually all the apps I had.

If you are considering to try this solution, remember to backup all the data that is not automatically saved on iCloud or any other cloud for all your applications.

**NOTE:** I also changed my phone (iPhone 7 Plus to iPhone 5S, sadly) but I believe it is not linked to the problem resolution.

Answer (score 0):

What email addresses that you have added to your device have calendar checked on as an option?

Its likely that your calendars are the possible culprit. Try turning off the ones you don't need.

Comment: Hi, as I said the only account with calendar checked is iCloud. I only use the others for Mail.

Comment: But do they have calendar checked? If not then find out how those events were added.

Comment: No, there is no other calendar checked (I thought that it was clear from my original question). I only have one calendar checked, the iCloud one and I already tried to remove it.

Comment: Then go to iCloud.com and see if you can delete the event there

Comment: I also tried this one too, didn't work... Birhday calendar (or its events) are not removable on icloud.com. Birthday calendar can be unchecked but this only affects icloud.com.

Comment: Then the last place I can think of that holds birthdays are your contacts list. Find the contact you are seeing the birthday for and then remove it from their contact info. If that doesn't fix it, then I'm not sure what the source would be. Maybe 3rd party apps/services. Check your contacts 1st.

Comment: Can you post a pic?

Comment: Pics uploaded, i edited my question including them.

Comment: This might be an icloud issue. Try calling apple support