# iPhone SE only syncs Notes with Exchange if I create a new Note

Tags: iphone, exchange-activesync

I use AkrutoSync, which presents an Exchange Server interface to my iPhoneSE.  If I create a new Note on my iPhone, it syncs with AkrutoSync.  If I edit or delete a note, however, it won't sync even after half an hour.  This seems to
be an issue with iPhone SW and how it determines when to sync.  Hence, the suggestions at https://www.akruto.com/fix-iphone-not-syncing-with-exchange do not seem to be relevant.  The annex below contains the details of my phone/AkrutoSync setup.  Is there anything I can do to troubleshoot this?

---

**Details of setup between iPhone SE and AkrutoSync**

The iPhone SE is as up-to-date as possible, iOS 14.4.  The laptop runs Windows 10, and I install updates whenever I am prompted.  AkrutoSync is version 5.2.42 (64-bit).  To the iPhone, it presents an Exchange interface for Outlook 2019 (desktop) on the laptop.  I choose to sync Calendar, Contacts, and Notes, but not Email.

On the iPhone, I connect to AkrutoSync as an Exchange Server.  I connect over home WiFi, not over the internet.  The laptop's IP address is static, so that should not be a problem.  The WiFi Access Point will dynamically assign IP addresses to other devices, but not to the laptop.

---

**What I tried**

For iPhone's Calendar app, I can manually initiate a sync from the iPhone by following [these few steps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/125743/254633).  However, there is no such counterpart for the Notes app.

I found out from a commentor that iOS 14.4 was actually not up-to-date, which surprised me as I normally see a notification that an update is available and I update right away.  I upgraded to the most recent iOS, version 15.2.1, which solved half the problem.  The iPhone now initiates a sync if I edit a Note, but not when I delete a Note.  I suspect this is not configurable, as I've never found indications of configurability for the years that I've looked.

Comment: iOS 14.4 is not the latest update for the original SE. It is not even the latest iOS 14, which is 14.8.1. The original SE will run the current iOS 15.2.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Huh! I usually get notified about updates, but now that I manually checked, you're right. After upgrading to iOS 15.2.1, it solves half the problem.  The iPhone now initiates a sync if I edit a Note, but not when I delete a Note.  I suspect this is not configurable, as I've never found indications of configurability for the years that I've looked.